# strange errors after migration win --> centos

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache, migration

hi there i've been trying to solve this little errors i keep getting after i migrated my webpage to CentOS 6.6 with httpd, php5, mariaDB from my windows 8 with a nearly stock XAMPP 1.7.3 with short_open_tags changed to ON and error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED with display_errors = On.

i've tried to change alot of stuff to get stuff working like a charm.. but it makes no sense atm.. here are one error i have --> Notice: Undefined variable: forums_arr in /var/www/html/shout.php
another one --> Notice: Use of undefined constant srt - assumed 'srt'

every page work perfectly on my windows server, but on my CentOS it just Fuc*s up..  i have thousands of functions and stuff that are built this way and sitt and searching up and fix every Constant makes it more worth using Windows instead of Linux.. i think there is a fix for this without lay 200 hours to change all the constants with a [' '].

i hope some out there have a solution for me!

if there is more info needed please let me know.

kind regards!

Comment: "every page work perfectly on my windows server" No, the problems are just ignored.

Comment: Is the php version the same? And the settings?

Comment: In my windows server the display_errors = On.

Comment: Ops, too quick to post.. error reporting is on on bith my servers, and i've tried to run my webpage on the latest setup of xampp and i guess there should be same releases